# C# Instantiate derived class from base constructor based on parameter type

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I have the following model (simplified):

Database models:

```
public abstract class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionA : Question
{
    public bool OptionA { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionB : Question
{
    public int OptionB { get; set; }
}
```

View models:

```
public abstract class QuestionModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected QuestionModel(Question question)
    {
        Text = question.Text;
    }
}

public class QuestionAModel : QuestionModel
{
    public bool OptionA { get; set; }

    public QuestionAModel(QuestionA questionA) : base(questionA)
    {
        OptionA = questionA.OptionA;
    }
}

public class QuestionBModel : QuestionModel
{
    public int OptionB { get; set; }

    public QuestionBModel(QuestionB questionB) : base(questionB)
    {
        OptionB = questionB.OptionB;
    }
}
```

Basically is to map database entities to view models, and I have for example, this controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        // Simulating questions from the database
        var questions = new List<Question>
        {
            new QuestionA { Id = 1, OptionA = true, Text = "fooA" },
            new QuestionB { Id = 1, OptionB = 1, Text = "fooB" }
        };

        var model = questions.Select(q => new QuestionModel(q)).ToList();

        return Json(model);
    }
}
```

This obiously don't compile because the `new QuestionModel(q)`

I know the type of every question from database, how I can create derived question models of the each question entity?

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling the constructor, create a [factory class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that will provide the correct implementation based on the type of the object that you have to create.

Notice that you will have to materialize your objects from the DB before calling the factory:

```
var model = questions.ToList().Select(q => QuestionFactory.CreateQuestion(q));
```

Comment: Nice, I will try this now!

Answer (score -1):

While trying to find an alternate solution to your problem, I came across a question which I hope someone can answer for me.

The following code works just fine, I declare a QuestionA object and create a QuestionModel of said type (A), which I finally add to a list of the generic QuestionModel type.

```
QuestionA qA = new QuestionA { Id = 1, OptionA = true, Text = "fooA" };
List<QuestionModel> lst = new List<QuestionModel>();
lst.Add(new QuestionAModel(qA));
```

However, supposedly this code follows the same logic, yet I cannot compile it

```
List<QuestionModel> model = new List<QuestionModel>();
questions.ForEach(q => model.Add(q.GetType().Equals(typeof(QuestionA)) ?
     new QuestionAModel((QuestionA)q) : new QuestionBModel((QuestionB)q)));
```

I apologize for deviating from OP's question

EDIT: So, technically, the following code will enable you to create the list of generic QuestionModels without having to modify the classes

```
var questions = new List<Question>
{
   new QuestionA { Id = 1, OptionA = true, Text = "fooA" },
   new QuestionB { Id = 1, OptionB = 1, Text = "fooB" }
};

List<QuestionModel> model = new List<QuestionModel>();
questions.ForEach(q => model.Add(q.GetType().Equals(typeof(QuestionA)) ?
            (QuestionModel)(new QuestionAModel((QuestionA)q)) : new QuestionBModel((QuestionB)q)));
```

Comment: An answer *answers* a question. This is not an answer. If you have a question and not an answer, *ask* a question.

Comment: @InBetween I consider it relevant because by solving this, you answer OP's question as well.

Comment: Be it relevant or not, is not the issue. Answers are for *answering*, not adding "relevant" questions.

Comment: That being said, your question is not relevant at all. Your code doesn't compile simply because the conditional expression can not find a valid type; explicitly telling the compiler the type of the conditional expression solves the issue: `questions.ForEach(q => model.Add(q.GetType().Equals(typeof(QuestionA)) ?
        (QuestionModel)(new QuestionAModel((QuestionA)q)) : new QuestionBModel((QuestionB)q)));` compiles just fine.

Comment: @InBetween Thanks, it now works as intended, I didn't expect that positioning of the (QuestionModel) cast you added, as it would appear that it would only apply to half of the condition output. My answer should now be of use to OP.

Comment: The other "half" of the conditional expression is implicitly convertible to `QuestionModel`, that is why it's not needed. The obvious question is then why the first cast is necessary? The answer is rather simple; when the compiler tries to figure out the type of the conditional expression it only considers the types explicitly involved, in your case `QuestionAModel` and `QuestionBModel`. Because there is no implicit conversion between the two, you get a compile time error.